# Get Bitmap directly instead of file in discCacheUtil

Tags: universal-image-loader

Am using Universal Image Loader for downloading images . Here are my Configuration and display Options.

```
File cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
    getApplicationContext())
    .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)).threadPoolSize(3)
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
    .build();

options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).resetViewBeforeLoading()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.bt_fine_dining).build();
```

Everything is working fine . But i want to check whether image is already exists or not. Using discCacheUtil am able to get file of image. [DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(imageUri, discCache)]. But is there any way to get directly Bitmap instead of file ??

And also if i specify both  cacheInMemory() and cacheOnDisc() ,will image be saved twice ?? Is there any extra consumption of memory here as image will be saved both in memory and disc ? please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView, displayOptions, new ImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    // Here loadedImage is you Bitmap object.
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `loadImageSync(String uri)` . It gives you bitmap.

If you want drawable from bitmap

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),imageLoader.loadImageSync(url);
```

Comment: But this will probably repeat the DiscCacheUtil.findInCache which you already did. So it's simpler to just load from the file.
Just do
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));